# No module named cairo - Mac

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, igraph, cairo

Why is it so effin' hard? Seems to be an ever-present issue..solved unclearly.

1. Searched on multiple github [pages](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/issues/825), advised to use `import cairocffi as cairo` instead, not working for me.
2. Some more on Stackoverflow, to add `sys.path.insert(0, "//anaconda/pkgs/cairo-1.14.10-0")` or something. But in fact, `sys.path` returns the directory anyway.

Quite sure installation done correctly as I can see under `conda list`.

[image]

Bad feeling this is gonna take a whole lot longer due to my little understanding of the os environment.

Can someone save me, all I want is to test `igraph.plot`

**Update**
`brew install py2cairo` somehow helped PYTOHNPATH on the terminal to figure out the library location, but it still fails to locate it in eclipse.

Of course added on Preference manually..why can't it import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import cairocffi as cairo` did it at the end.

Had to install `cairocffi`, on top of all the manual reinstall.
 (I had brew install, Mac still accepted the install)

If you want to plot using `igraph`, no need to hassle with importing any of these libraries explicitly.

Related thread on superuser. Posted some useful references some may come across.