# WeasyPrint Python module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, macos-ventura, weasyprint

I installed WeasyPrint on MacOS Ventura 13.4.1 using Homebrew. It seems to have installed properly,

```
which weasyprint

\usr\local\weasyprint
```

When I try to load the Python module however, I get the error,

```
python3 weasytest.py
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'weasyprint'
```

Some clues:

- I'm using Python 3.11.6
- Python is looking for modules in the following directories,

```
python3 -m site                                                                               
sys.path = [  '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python311.zip',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages',
]
```

- Homebrew looks to have placed the python module in `/usr/local/Cellar/weasyprint/60.1_1/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/weasyprint`

I can copy the module and a few of the dependencies (e.g. cssselect2, html5lib, pyphen) to one of the places that Python checks, but then eventually I get a missing module that isn't in the Cellar directory (specifically fontTools). I've tried upgrading brew, as well as running brew doctor and cleanup. Is there a missing link somewhere that I need to create?

Comment: Noting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43623034/5410751) to a similar question (especially the final bullet point of the answer), are you using a python environment that is managed by homebrew or by something like pip/Anaconda?

Comment: I believe I've only used Brew on this machine and not Anaconda. Is there an easy way to verify that?

Comment: If you're using an environment, you should have a prefix in your terminal indicating the name of the environment; you'd probably know if you were using one I suppose.
From what I can tell, `brew install weasyprint` should be sufficient. The only other thing I can think of is to add `export PYTHONPATH=$export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/Cellar` to your `.bashrc`-file.

Comment: `pip3 install weasyprint`?

Comment: Perhaps it's relevant that I'm using zsh instead of bash. Anyways I added the PYTHONPATH to the .zshrc file, and no luck.

Comment: Would installing it through pip do something different? Brew is the recommended way to install weasyprint.